# Print dice rolls on a single line

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
import random

while True:   
    num_side = int(input("Which type of dice do You wish to roll? Select from: [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100]: "))
    num_dice = int(input("How many dice do You wish to roll?: "))
    rolls = []
    for die in range(num_dice):
        dice_roll = random.randint(1, num_side)
        rolls.append(dice_roll)
        print ("You rolled: {}".format(rolls))
```

When the num_dice input == anything greater than 1 the output is printed over multiple lines, for instance if num_dice ==  4 the output would look like

```
You rolled: [x]

You rolled: [x,x]

You rolled: [x,x,x]

You rolled: [x,x,x,x]
```

How could I fix this to print the rolls on a single line?

Comment: If you don't want the print statement in the loop, then don't indent it to place it in the loop.  That's the only issue -- indentation is absolutely critical in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `print()` statement over one indent, and the results will only appear once all dice have been rolled.

```py
import random    
while True:   
    num_side = int(input("Which type of dice do You wish to roll? Select from: [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100]: "))
    num_dice = int(input("How many dice do You wish to roll?: "))
    rolls = []
    for die in range(num_dice):
        dice_roll = random.randint(1, num_side)
        rolls.append(dice_roll)
    print("You rolled: {}".format(rolls))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the print statement as follows

```
        print ("You rolled: {}".format(rolls),end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

just
`step your print() function out of your for loop`
like next

```py
import random

while True:   
    num_side = int(input("Which type of dice do You wish to roll? Select from: [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100]: "))
    num_dice = int(input("How many dice do You wish to roll?: "))
    rolls = []
    for die in range(num_dice):
        dice_roll = random.randint(1, num_side)
        rolls.append(dice_roll)
        
    print ("You rolled: {}".format(rolls))
```